# Image directory not found in texstudio

Tags: graphics, texstudio

I'm learning how to insert an image in TeXStudio on Mac OS. I tried to drag the image directly to the pdf, which gives the following:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \author{Yifu Zhang}
    \begin{document}

    Here is a photo I wanna share


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Users/yifu.zhang/Desktop/Presentation12}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:presentation12}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

However, I got error message saying file not found. I thought it was because of the .png problem,  so I tried .jpeg and added the .jpeg in the end like this:

```
   \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Users/yifu.zhang/Desktop/Presentation12.jpeg}
```

which  still doesn't work. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Ingeneral place the image in the same folder og in a subfolder of the the folder where the `.tex` file is. Then it is also easier to send to someone else at a later date.

Comment: Which Operating system are you on? I'm guessing this is either Windows or Mac. In that case `Users/yifu.zhang/...` is probably an absolute path, but it is incomplete, on widows it should probably have `c:/` in front and something else if it is a Mac.

Comment: @daleif Yes this is on Mac. For the subfolder thing I don't know how to save files in a subfolder unfortunately, so I'll post another question on this after the cooldown.

Comment: How to save a file in a subfolder is not LaTeX related, this is basic featyure of knowing how you use your OS. On a mac I would just use Finder. Otherwise just make sure the file is in the same folder as the `.tex` file and use `   \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Presentation12.jpeg}`